# .Net OData ServiceReference SaveChanges Returns OData

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, odata, service-reference, savechanges

I am using an OData Service Reference to create a Purchase Order.
When I call the OData SaveChanges method it does save my PO and somewhere in the response is the POID.

Fiddler shows me that OData is returned from an OData SaveChanges call.
[image: fiddler response]

My DataServiceResponses(0).Headers looks like this in the watch window:
[image: .net debugger]

While I could get the Location response and scrape the POID (in this case it is 0000000035 or 36) but I should be able to get an object back in the form of the odata shown by Fiddler.  I would rather make a second call to re-query the PO information.

Everyone always asks for code -- fine, here's some code:
[image: code sample]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the object is populated with server data.

[image: revised code]

That is really cool!